# How to align btn-group inside btn-toolbar to right bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I have a `btn-toolbar` that has two `btn-group`. By default the groups are aligned to the left. But I need the second toolbar to be aligned to the right.

This is my code:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="btn-toolbar rounded" role="toolbar" aria-label="Toolbar with button groups" id="main-toolbar">
  <div class="btn-group mr-2" role="group" aria-label="First group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-md text-center rounded" id="toolbar-button">
      <span class="fa fa-edit fa-2x"></span><br>
      <span class="toolbar-item-text">Edit</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group mr-2 float-right" role="group" aria-label="Second group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-md text-center rounded" id="toolbar-button" id="measurement-button">
        <span class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></span><br>
        <span class="toolbar-item-text">Measurements</span>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

This works for me when I use `pull-right` in bootstrap 3, but when using bootstrap 4 (which includes popperJS), it does not work.
I have read a lot of answers on stack, but none of them work for bootstrap 4, and not where the `btn-group` is inside a `btn-toolbar`.
Here is the result I get:
[image]

But I need the measurements button in the right corner, not in the next line. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use bootstarp 4 `.ml-auto` class in the second `btn-group`. It will align the `btn-group` to right as it has `margin-left: auto` property

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="btn-toolbar rounded" role="toolbar" aria-label="Toolbar with button groups" id="main-toolbar">
  <div class="btn-group mr-2" role="group" aria-label="First group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-md text-center rounded" id="toolbar-button">
      <span class="fa fa-edit fa-2x"></span><br>
      <span class="toolbar-item-text">Edit</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group ml-auto" role="group" aria-label="Second group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-md text-center rounded" id="toolbar-button" id="measurement-button">
        <span class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></span><br>
        <span class="toolbar-item-text">Measurements</span>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```